# How is Jquery converted in meteor?

Tags: jquery, meteor, mapbox

I am working with the Mapbox api and I have this jquery that meteor is not picking up:

```
        $.get(directionsUrl, function(data) {
        // Do something with the directions returned from the API.
        var route = data.routes[0].geometry.coordinates;
        route = route.map(function(point) {
            // Turns out if we zoom out we see that the lat/lngs are flipped,
            // which is why it didn't look like they were being added to the
            // map. We can invert them here before drawing.
            return [point[1], point[0]];
        });
        polyline.setLatLngs(route);
    })
```

How would something like this work with meteor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it already?

It should work as is without particular issue. `jquery` package should be added by default in your Meteor project and work as regular.

Make sure your `data` is properly converted to a JS object.

If you still have issues it would be worth adding error messages you may have in your console.